# Tensorflow classification label 0 and 1

Tags: tensorflow, label, classification

I'm working on a simple classification problem. I proceeded through the example and created a model.

I arranged the tag column as given below.

`label 0 1 1 0 0 1` 
As a result, I wanted to test the system with samples. But it does value as a percentage.

I expect it to give 2 correct values, either 0 or 1.

example codes;

```
input_dict = {name: tf.convert_to_tensor([value]) for name, value in sample.items()}
predictions = reloaded_model.predict(input_dict)
prob = tf.nn.sigmoid(predictions[0])

print(
    "This particular pet had a %.1f percent probability "
    "of getting adopted." % (100 * prob)
)
```

What code will result in 0 and 1?

thank you.

Comment: You can use preds = np.argmax(predictions , axis = 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What to do depends on how you model was constructed. With only two labels you are doing binary classification. If in your model the last dense layer has 1 neuron then it is set up for binary classification. In that case your loss function in model.compile should be

```
loss=BinaryCrossentropy
```

Model.predict in that case will produce a single value probability output. You can just use an if statement to determine the class. If the probability is less than.5 it is one class, if greator or equal to .5 it is the other class. Now you may have constructed your model where the last dense layer has 2 neurons. In that case you should be using either sparse_categorical_crossentropy if the labels were integers or categorical_crossentropy if the labels were one hot encoded as your loss function. Model.predict in this case will produce two probabilities as the output. You want to select the index of with the highest probability as the class.
You can do that with class=np.argmax(predictions)